# More than 30 search results at google play

Tags: android, google-play

Google has made the Play Store new layout and design. To track the store position of apps, is there a way to get more than 30 search results at google play in a desktop browser, maybe via browser console or something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can try scraping the pages you want and parsing the results.

You can scrape using something like selenium: https://www.selenium.dev

Using browser automation you can navigate links, so even if the number of results per page changes, you can just follow the link to the next page and scrape the following results.

Answer (score 1):

if you apply a time delay on selenium `(ex: time.sleep())` you can automate and search any site any number of times.